# Unity 2020.1.0f1 (IL2CPP error for method 'System.Void) error

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, compiler-errors

Just formatted my Mac and put a clean install of Catalina on and, then updated Unity to 2020.1.0f1 loaded my project that's been working fine on Catalina before reinstalling and updating Unity, but now when I try and build I get this error.

```
IL2CPP error for method 'System.Void Unity.GeneratedNetworkCode::_WriteArrayVector3_None(UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkWriter,UnityEngine.Vector3[])' in assembly '/Users/kevin/Desktop/AR_Army_New/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll' Additional information: Hash code collision on value 09716D6B6B7159FFA4DDC4AAF2722973A3FF4FC8
```

Anyone know what's gong on please ?

Comment: What's your target platform and detailed error message from the build log?

Comment: Hi, Don't know what it was but opened a new project and imported scripts, models, prefabs ect from the old project and it's all working fine now, so this can be closed now. Unity seem to think it's a bug https://forum.unity.com/threads/il2cpp-error-for-method-system-void.940908/